# Subvalue and level

Tags: expression-manipulation

I'm interested in the arguments of `f` in expressions like

```
f[a]@f[b]@f[c]
```

By argument I mean what is here `a`, `b` and `c`. I would like to know the arguments and in what order they appear. For example, the order of the arguments in

```
 f[d]@(2 x f[b])@f[c]@f[q]
```

is

```
 {d, b, c, q}
```

How can I find this from the above expression?
I tried to use `Level[]`, but the Subvalue construction is hindering me.

Comment: What would be an appropriate title for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
Cases[f[d]@(2 x f[b])@f[c]@f[q], f[x_] :> x, {-2}, Heads -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
expr = f[d]@(2 x f[b])@f[c]@f[q];
Extract[expr, Position[expr, f[_]], First]
   {d, b, c, q}
```

Note that `Extract[]` and `Position[]` are able to handle expressions with any head, not just lists.